How can I make reverse proxy for websocket requests on apache
I have a website written on Laravel with Reverb for websockets. Everything works except websockets. They are sent from the browser to the server in the form wss://mydomain.com/app (which throw an error). Server listen on 0.0.0.0:8080 for them. For nginx this works with:
server {
    ...
 
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
 
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }
 
    ...
}

But my server is on apache. How can I make incoming requests wss://mydomain.com/app being redirected on local address 0.0.0.0:8080 ?

Does this answer your question? How can I use Apache as a reverse proxy for https?
